# Finding the current page in Word document

Tags: python-2.7, ms-word, pywin32, win32com

I've successfully managed to use win32 COM to grab details about the page numbers of a word document. However, when I try to use `mydoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)`
I know that the file has been read into memory properly because `mydoc.Content.Text` prints out all the content.
 I get a "wdActiveEndPageNumber is Not Defined" error. Anyone know why this is happening and how to fix this? And is there some python documentation or am I stuck looking at VB and C# on msdn?

```
import win32com.client
 word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
 mydoc=word.DOcuments.Open("path:\\to\\file")
 mydoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `wdActiveEndPageNumber` is a constant that not defined by win32com, until you generate the COM type library from the application. Try this:

```
from win32com.client.gencache import EnsureDispatch
from win32com.client import constants
word = EnsureDispatch("Word.Application")
mydoc = word.Documents.Open("path:\\to\\file")
mydoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Information(constants.wdActiveEndPageNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the enumerated number.  You can find this using the object browser in word.  Just got into the vba editor, press f2 then enter wdActiveEndPageNumber as the search term,.  When you select it in the results it wil show you its integer value.  Then put that in your code.